# JavaFX - Weird ComboBox behavior, items not updating properly

Tags: javafx

There seems to be some bug with the ComboBox where item labels are not properly updated if modified. Here's a demo (I'm using JavaFX 21)

```
public class Example extends Application {
    ComboBox<Person> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
    Button button = new Button("Press me");
    GridPane pane = new GridPane(50,0);
    ObservableList<Person> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.add(comboBox,0,0);
        pane.add(button, 1,0);
        button.setOnAction(event->{
            list.get(1).setName(list.get(1).getName() + "o");
            list.add(new Person("New"));
            //FIX?
            //comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.emptyObservableList());
            //comboBox.setItems(list);
        });

        Person p1 = new Person("Alice");
        Person p2 = new Person("Bob");
        Person p3 = new Person("Clyde");
        list.addAll(p1, p2, p3);

        comboBox.setItems(list);
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        comboBox.setConverter(new StringConverter<>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Person person) {
                return person.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public Person fromString(String s) {
                return null;
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Help!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}

class Person{
    public SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person(String name){
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String getName() { return name.get(); }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name.set(name); }
}
```

Pressing the button will add an o at the end of Bob's name, however the ComboBox is kinda unreliable at reflecting that change. If you expand the ComboBox first, then press the button, then expand the ComboBox again, you will see the second item is Bob when it should be Bobo. However, the moment you select Bob from the list it will decide to update it to Bobo. Selecting any other item from the list (or doing anything else really) doesn't update Bob. On the other hand, doing stuff like adding items to the list works fine, and a New person appears at the same time that Bob stays the same.

Is this behavior weird or am I doing something I'm not supposed to? <s>The only workaround I've found is setting the list to an empty one and then immediately setting it to the proper one again, which is simple enough but kindof annoying.</s> Nevermind, even that doesn't work when I tried it in a more complex program. Is there a proper solution?

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem, apparently you need to add an extractor to the list in order for the combobox to properly listen to changes to object properties. The solution is to simply declare the list like so

```
ObservableList<Person> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(person -> new Observable[]{person.name});
```

That way the combobox list will update if there's any changes to an item's name property. This is probably obvious but I somehow haven't had to use extractors up until this point and I didn't know about them, I'm leaving the post up in case it helps someone else